# angularjs + jquery mobile scope issue with multipage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-mobile, scope, url-routing

I need to make angularjs and jquery mobile coexist within a mobile application and to leave routing logic to jquery mobile (i.e. not using ngRoute module but jquerymobile's ajax dom injection instead).

If I use jquery mobile's single page template there are no problem with the scope, but if I open external html pages via ajax it seems that angular looses its scope.

Here is the snippet:
http://embed.plnkr.co/4Ct8I9YnGq0CpRmnsVgO/preview